# How to extract client certificate from request in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

How can I extract a client certificate from an HTTP request in Laravel? Does [Request](https://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Http/Request.html) class provide any means for the purpose? My final goal is to get a client certificate in PEM format.

Comment: Anything in `dd($_SERVER['SSL_CLIENT_CERT'])` ?

Comment: [Related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212119/php-and-x-509-authentication-checking-certificate-issuer)